# Collecting multipolygons into a single multipolygon with ST_Collect() in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I would like to collect 50,000 individual multipolygons into one big multipolygon. Unfortunately when I perform `ST_Collect(geom)` it bundles them into a geometry collection and cannot be cast as `::geometry(MultiPolygonZ, 2193)` which is of no use to me.

How do I get prevent this from happening? I have tried wrapping the `ST_Collect()` in a `ST_CollectionExtract()` but that merely returns the original 50,000 multipolygons.

Here is the code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
SELECT
  1::INT as id,
  ST_Collect(geom)::geometry(MultiPolygonZ,2193)
FROM
  old_table
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [St_Union()](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Union.html) instead?

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
SELECT
  1::INT as id,
  ST_Union(geom)::geometry(MultiPolygonZ,2193)
FROM
  old_table
```

If this originates Topology problems (**GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException**) you can use [ST_Collect()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) wrapped with a [St_buffer()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) with 0 distance:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
SELECT
  1::INT as id,
  ST_Buffer(ST_Collect(geom),0)::geometry(MultiPolygonZ,2193)
FROM
  old_table
```

Comment: The `ST_Union` worked but I'd really like an answer to a `ST_Collect`! I will mark it as correct for now :-)

Comment: I didn't require the `ST_Buffer` but thanks for the heads up. A good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ST_Collect` to do this, you just need to break apart the inputs first using `ST_Dump`:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT
  1::int AS id,
  ST_Collect(geom)
FROM 
  (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom FROM oldtable) sq;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your question is:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
SELECT
  1::INT as id,
  ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Collect(geom), 3) geom
FROM
  old_table
```